# Why do I get a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, jsp, numberformatexception

I make a button that changes the status of the flight. But I receive, NumberFormatException. Below I presented the methods where I get data from the database.

```
private Flight getFlight(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DBException {
        Flight flight = new Flight();
        flight.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
        flight.setName(rs.getString(NAME));
        flight.setStartPoint(rs.getString("STARTPOINT"));
        flight.setEndPoint(rs.getString("ENDPOINT"));
        flight.setNumber(rs.getInt("NUMBER"));
        flight.setDepartureDate(rs.getString("DEPARTURE_DATE"));
        flight.setDepartureTime(rs.getInt("DEPARTURE_TIME"));
        flight.setStatus(rs.getBoolean("STATUS"));
        flight.setAircompanyId(rs.getInt("AIRCOMPANY_ID"));
        return flight;
    }

public Flight findFlightById (int id) throws DBException{
        Flight flight = null;
        for (Flight f : getFlights()) {
            if (f.getId() == id) {
                flight = f;
                break;
            }
        }
        return flight;
    }

public boolean updateFlightStatusById(int id)throws DBException{
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        Boolean status = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(UPDATE_FLIGHT_STATUS);
            Flight flight = findFlightById(id);
            int k = 1;
            if (flight.isStatus()) {
                pstmt.setBoolean(k++, false);
                status = true;
            } else {
                pstmt.setBoolean(k++, true);
                status = false;
            }
            pstmt.setInt(k++, flight.getId());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            rollback(con);
            throw new DBException("cannot update flight status", e);
        } finally {
            close(con);
            close(pstmt);
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Then I call the received method in another class, which returns the path to the jsp page

```
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("flightId")); // here i get an exception
            db.updateFlightStatusById(id);
session.setAttribute("flights", flight);
```

Also I will provide some of the code with the jsp page.

```
<c:forEach var="bean" items="${sessionScope.flights}">
<td><form action="controller" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="getFlights">
                            <input type="hidden" name="flightId" value="${bean.id}">
                            <c:if test="${bean.status eq true}">
                                <input type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="correct"/>">
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${bean.status eq false}">
                                <input type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="incorrect"/>">
                            </c:if>

                        </form></td>
</c:forEach>
```

I already did a similar task, but there was no such error. What was I wrong about? I will be grateful for the help!

My sql request 
`private static final String UPDATE_FLIGHT_STATUS = "UPDATE FLIGHT SET status=? where id=?";`

Comment: So, what exactly is the value of `request.getParameter("flightId")`?  The stack trace of the exception will tell you what value it's failing to parse.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), it's pretty straightforward.

**Integer.parseInt(String)**

> **Parameters:**
>       s - a String containing the int representation to be parsed
>   **Returns:**
>       the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
>   **Throws:**
>       NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

**NumberFormatException**

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

If you debug your code you will find that the `id` variable is either `null` or has some other value that can't be converted to an integer. Check your request parameter map to see that a `flightId` parameter exists and is not null.

Comment: No problem. If you feel the answer was satisfactory please consider marking it as accepted.